# line at a time work progress filter for scripting

Tags: scripting

So lets say I have a script that works on groups of files, and does several different sorts of operations.

Printing out a filename as it gets processed helps give an idea of how well things are going.

But the volume of data would drown out other message, like what stage the script is in.

What I'd like is something that reads standard input and changes newline to a cartridge return and the termcap sequence to clear to end of line. (or even a return, a terminal width of spases and another return)

Using this, the output of individual stages will show up as a single changing line without scrolling (unless there is a line wrap.  oh well, one problem at a time)

I could write this, but it would seem useful enough that someone had probably done it before, but I have no idea what the name of that filter might be.

Has it been done?

(using `someprogram | dialog --progressbox 1 80` is close to what I am looking for )

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is have a progress line that is constantly updated without scrolling, so here's something I have written for this:

```
files="$(ls /some/folder)"
elems="$(echo "$files" | wc -w)"
cnt=0
for name in $files; do
    let "cnt+=1"
    printf "\rMyScript - Processing file %3i of %3i: %.40s" "$cnt" "$elems" "$name"
done
echo
```

This gives you a single line e.g. `MyScrpit - Processing file 5 of 14: foo.a`.

You could also modify this to work via pipe similar to `dialog --progressbox`:

```
total="$1"
cnt=0
while IFS='$\n' read -r name; do
    let "cnt+=1"
    printf "\rProcessing file %3i of %3i: %.40s" "$cnt" "$total" "$name"
done < /dev/stdin
echo
```

Of course you can leave out the counter and just print the filenames (if you don't want to provide the total count beforehand as a parameter).
The fixed field length in printf is going to ensure that their will be no line-wrapping going to happen (unless you terminal window is even smaller).